# Diagnosing reason for Invalid Number of FixUps deserialisation Error

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am getting "invalid number of fixups" error when deserializing a blob of data out of a database and I am looking for a way to find out where the issue with the data/code is.

Basically the guy before the guy before me thought it would be a good idea to just store vast amounts of important data as a serialized blob in a table in the database. Since he left the code has been altered multiple times but I need to get important data out of an old database for a customer.

So I have the updated object, but no record of the previous object that was serialized in the first place.

How can I go about finding what field is missing, has been renamed or what name has been reused to cause this issue?

Anyway I can get more detailed information about why this is failing?

Here is an example of the deserialisation code.

```
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter()
                {
                    AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
                    Binder = new TypeRedirector()
                };

                return (T)bf.UnsafeDeserialize(ms, null);
            }//using
```

Comment: Additional information is needed here. How is the data being stored (XML, JSON)? Have you tried validating the data using any web tools? Likewise, we have no idea what you are trying to deserialize to. Deserializing code and data are required. Otherwise best option is to start reading up on serialization

Comment: Added example of my deserialisation code.